# What does it mean if I can not get 0 error on very small training dataset?

Tags: python, keras, deep-learning

In order to validate if the network can potentially learn often people try to overfit on the small dataset.

I can not reach 0 error with my dataset but the output looks like that network memorizes the training set. (MPAE ~1 %)

Is it absolutely necessary to get 0 error in order to prove that my network potentially works on my dataset?

Comment: Hi. I think your question might be a better fit for [Cross Validated SE](https://stats.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: How small? Can you show an example of the input/output and the layout of your network? It's hard to understand if there is a problem otherwise.

Comment: input: 64*2000 sampled time series data, output 128*256 matrix with values in range 1300-1800. Network is an hourglass network with 13 layers and the task is a regression.

Comment: By small dataset I intended 200 for this task

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Short answer: No

Reason:

1. It may be that a small number of examples are miss labeled. In the case of classification, try to identify which examples it is unable to correctly classify. This will tell you whether your network has learnt all it can.
2. It can also happen if your data has no pattern that can be learnt - if the data is essentially random.
3. If the data is noisy, sometimes the noise will mask the features that are required for prediction.
4. If a dataset is chaotic in the sense that the features vary quickly and dramatically between (and among) labels - if your data follows a very complex (non-smooth) function.

Hope this helps!